# 3ds max treating a quad as an ngon

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

I tried to select non-quad polygons in my model and 3ds max is selecting a polygon which appears to me a quad. If it isn't quad how to convert it to a quad? (please see the image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnQQy.gif

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem and made a video tutorial on this. There were some hidden overlapping vertices which caused these "quad-like" ngons. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaVHTNxVpZU